# Can we find executable lines of code in a C/C++ source file with gcov

Tags: c, gcc, gcov, lcov, lines-of-code

gcov primarily is a code coverage tool. However, is there any way we can find LOC (excluding comments...etc) with gcov?

It must be easy for gcov to get that information, but I didn't find any documentation on that.

Also, let me know if you know any other tool which can calculate lines of code in such manner.

Comment: there's an option in lcov "--initial". It will generate a baseline coverage information which contains LOC and lot more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also look at [SLOCCount](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/), which is available in packages on most Linux distributions.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to another tool for just counting line of code(LOC) then please go for `cloc`.
For more info regarding supported os and installation go to http://cloc.sourceforge.net/.